# JavaScript will not change display to "none"

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to add a click event handler to a button that will cause it to change the CSS display property of a sign-in form to 'none'.

```js
// make the form disappear when the user clicks initSignUpBtn
const initSignUpBtn = document.querySelector(".btn signup-btn");
initSignUpBtn.addEventListener("click", () =>{
    document.getElementById("signinForm").style.display="none";
});
```

```html
<form class="signin-form" id="signinForm">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="email" class="email-input" id="emailInput" placeholder="Email or username">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="password" class="pass-input" id="passwordInput" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
        <label class="form-check-label">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox"> Remember me<a class="need-help" href="#">Need Help?</a>
        </label>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn signin-btn" id="signinbtn">Sign in</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn signup-btn" id="initSignUpBtn">New? Sign up!</button>

</form>
```

I added an event listener of type 'click' to the button, and wrote an anonymous function that changes the display property of the form to 'none' but this did not work.

Comment: try like this: const initSignUpBtn = document.querySelector(".signup-btn");

Comment: Use the [browser console (dev tools)](//webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`), read any errors. You’ll see an error message saying that `initSignUpBtn` is `null`. `.btn signup-btn` selects all `<signup-btn>` elements somewhere inside elements with `class="btn"`. Since you don’t have such elements, `document.querySelector` returns `null`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your querySelector is incorrect. Why not use `document.getElementById("initSignUpBtn")` since you have an ID on it? If you do want to use `querySelector`, it should be `document.querySelector(".btn.signup-btn")` or `document.querySelector(".signup-btn")`.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much Zac Anger, that did the trick! Thank you for being kind to a newbie programmer, and pointing out my silly mistake. It looks like I made the following two mistakes:
1) I was using getElementsById  (plural) instead of getElementById

2) I was not putting the period between btn and signup-btn.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this logic :

```html
<form class="signin-form" id="signinForm">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="email" class="email-input" id="emailInput" placeholder="Email or username">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="password" class="pass-input" id="passwordInput" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
        <label class="form-check-label">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox"> Remember me<a class="need-help" href="#">Need Help?</a>
        </label>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn signin-btn" id="signinbtn">Sign in</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn signup-btn" id="initSignUpBtn">New? Sign up!</button>

</form>
```

```js
const initSignUpBtn = document.querySelector(".btn.signup-btn");
initSignUpBtn.addEventListener("click", () =>{
    document.getElementById("signinForm").style.display="none";
});
```

```html
<form class="signin-form" id="signinForm">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="email" class="email-input" id="emailInput" placeholder="Email or username">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="password" class="pass-input" id="passwordInput" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
        <label class="form-check-label">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox"> Remember me<a class="need-help" href="#">Need Help?</a>
        </label>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn signin-btn" id="signinbtn">Sign in</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn signup-btn" id="initSignUpBtn">New? Sign up!</button>

</form>
```